# Flutter AAPT: error: unexpected element <appliation> found in <manifest>

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart, gradle

I am trying to build app using `flutter build apk  --release` but it is throwing following error. The code is running in debug mode but no idea why it is not building in `--release` mode

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Android resource linking failed
     /build/app/intermediates/packaged_manifests/release/AndroidManifest.xml:16: AAPT: error: unexpected element <appliation> found in <manifest>.
```

Here is my `AndroidManifest.xml` Configuration.

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.test">
   <appliation
        android:label="Test"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/launcher_icon">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme">
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
       <meta-data
           android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
           android:value="" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </appliation>
</manifest>
```

And Packages, I am using are:-

```yaml
another_flushbar: ^1.10.28
cloud_firestore: ^3.1.5
cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
firebase_auth: ^3.3.4
firebase_core: ^1.10.6
flutter:
  sdk: flutter
flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.9.2
flutter_otp_text_field: ^1.0.0
geocoding: 2.0.1
geolocator: 8.0.1
google_fonts: ^2.1.0
google_maps_flutter: ^2.1.1
provider: ^6.0.1
```

Thanks For Your Help!

Comment: `appliation` sounds weird, isn't it `application` ?

Comment: ya it's `appliation` on the debug console.

Comment: I mean you should rename the tag in the XML to `application`, see here : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro

Comment: It's not working, i renamed to `application` but it again changes to `appliation`. The error code detect to `build/app/intermediates/packaged_manifests/release/AndroidManifest.xml:16`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I googled for the issue and try many approach but cannot able to resolve error. Some configuration on android part was causing the error, idk what was that, so i decided to delete `android` directory and regenerate with `flutter create .` and was able to resolve the given errors.

steps i followed to resolve

```
rm -rf android/ # remove android directory
```

```
flutter create . # generate fresh new android directory
```

Comment: ```Invalid project name: 'flutter' - this will conflict with Flutter package dependencies.```